# Defining an index as date time in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, netcdf4

Having used R for several years, I'm taking the plunge and learning python, starting by editing some existing code.

I have a time variable that has been imported from a netCDF file as follows:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np

import datetime
import pandas as pd

f = nc.Dataset(fname)
    time = nc.num2date(f.variables['time'][:],
                       f.variables['time'].units)
    nc_dims = [dim for dim in f.dimensions]
```

The time variable is added to a column called `'dates'` in a dataframe `df`:

```
df['dates'] = time
```

That is then converted to an index:

```
df = df.set_index('dates')
```

Two new columns are defined for the dataframe, both requiring the index to be of the correct datetime data format (I think).

```
df['season'] = (df.index.month) % 12 + 3) // 3
df['day'] = np.floor(df.index.to_julian_date().values - 0.5)
```

However, when the code is run in command prompt, errors result:

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'month' ; and
>
> 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_julian_date'

This makes me think that the index object is not correctly defined as a date time object (hence the month call doesn't work) and it doesn't know that it can convert the object to julian date format.  Either that, or I am missing a vital package.

I have tried converting the index using:

```
pd.Timestamp(time)
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex('dates'))
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

But get errors indicating the index object is already in date time format:

> TypeError: Cannot convert input [[cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011-01-01
>   00:30:00.13) TypeError:  is
>   not convertible to datetime TypeError:  is not convertible to datetime

I feel like I'm missing a vital piece of the puzzle, knowing that this code does run in my colleagues environment.  Any help anyone can offer that may help me debug this greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Here is a small sample of the data:

```
                           iveg_1  iveg_2  patchfrac_1  patchfrac_2
dates
2011-01-01 00:30:00.13       2       6          1.0          0.0
2011-01-01 01:00:00          2       6          1.0          0.0
2011-01-01 01:30:00          2       6          1.0          0.0
2011-01-01 02:00:00.13       2       6          1.0          0.0
2011-01-01 02:30:00          2       6          1.0          0.0
2011-01-01 03:00:00          2       6          1.0          0.0
2011-01-01 03:30:00.13       2       6          1.0          0.0
2011-01-01 04:00:00          2       6          1.0          0.0
2011-01-01 04:30:00          2       6          1.0          0.0
2011-01-01 05:00:00.13       2       6          1.0          0.0
```

Comment: Please provide a link to a sample of your dataset?

Comment: which one?  The netCDF file or the dataframe?

Comment: It would be great if you edit your question by providing a reproducible sample of your dataframe "df" for us to recreate your dataframe back

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Is that what you need?  It doesn't have the class types for the dates column though.

Comment: Dear Alison. It would be great if you create a new dataframe in python having just 2-3 rows of your data and all columns in whatever datatypes you have it currently in your df. And then post the code which you used to create your dataframe. The code should be in the format of "df = pd.DataFrame(YourData)". Refer this link for more details: https://datatofish.com/create-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: Sounds great, I'd love to comply and totally understand why you are asking!  Unfortunately my skills are not even that advanced!  You can see that the data is in a date format, and the type error tells me the data type is 'cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011-01-01 00:30:00.13) ' so the key question, is how do I get the month variable out of data in that format? Perhaps that's a better question to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting to string first:

```
df['dates'] = time
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'].astype('str'))
df = df.set_index('dates')
```

Verify you are working with a `DateTimeIndex` using `df.info()`.

The `DateTimeIndex` object will then allow you to extract date information from it, e.g. its month or convert `.to_julian_date()`.

Comment: `type(df.index)` is maybe a bit more straightforward way to check for its type. Should yield `pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex`.

Comment: Thank-you!  The second line of code did the trick.  Out of curiosity, do you know why converting it to a sting would work?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime()` knows how to handle a string and to convert it but isn't able to do so for a variable of type `cftime.DatetimeGregorian` (hence the error message you shared). For a full list of accepted dtypes see [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).